# ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: angular

If I set full template type check

```
    {
        "compileOnSave": false,
        "compilerOptions": {
            ///...
            "target": "es6",
            "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
            "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
        },
        "angularCompilerOptions": {
            "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
            "enableIvy": false
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

> ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable

So how can I figure out where exactly the problem is?

i have a big project.

Answer (score 0):

please set:

```
 "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
```

should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Comments are not supported with JSON. Additionally, there is a syntax error with your code because of a wrong 'comma'.
Your code should be like that:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "enableIvy": false
    }
}
```